# div wraps not stretching down

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I cannot get this red div wrap to stretch down past the other divs. I've tried using the clear:both; attribute, and a few other combinations, but to no avail. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

```css
#footer-wrap{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#dc0000;
}
#footer{
 width:960px;
 height:auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
 background:#dc0000;
 padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
.footer-class{
 width:126px;
 height:200px;
 float:left;
 background:#093;
 margin:0 30px 0 0;
}
.footer-class-end{
 width:180px;
 float:right;
 background:#FF0;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-wrap">
<div id="footer">
<div class="footer-class"><h5>products</h5></div>
<div class="footer-class"><h5>support</h5></div>
<div class="footer-class"><h5>information</h5></div>
<div class="footer-class"><h5>legal</h5></div>
<div class="footer-class"><h5>interactive</h5></div>
<div class="footer-class-end"><h5>twitter</h5></div>

</div></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to clear left `float` with `clear: left`.

```css
#footer-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #dc0000;
}
#footer {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #dc0000;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
.footer-class {
  width: 126px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: #093;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.footer-class-end {
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  background: #FF0;
}
.clear {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-wrap">
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>products</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>support</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>information</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>legal</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>interactive</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class-end">
      <h5>twitter</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [w3.org - Floats and clearing](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Floats_and_clearing) - [CSS-Tricks - What is "Float"?](http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

A new way clearing floats without extra markup is by putting `clear` at `:after` pseudo-element (but has less browser compatibility).

```
#footer:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
```

```css
#footer-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #dc0000;
}
#footer {
  width: 960px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #dc0000;
  padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
}
#footer:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
.footer-class {
  width: 126px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
  background: #093;
  margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}
.footer-class-end {
  width: 180px;
  float: right;
  background: #FF0;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer-wrap">
  <div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>products</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>support</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>information</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>legal</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class">
      <h5>interactive</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-class-end">
      <h5>twitter</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference: [MDN - Clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

Answer (score 0):

Or add just `overflow:hidden` to wrapper. http://jsfiddle.net/5a8vmr4r/1/

This is well known issue with floated elements...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `clearfix`, thats why it doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/5a8vmr4r/3/